# C++: Unable to understand the compilation error

Tags: c++

I drew up this sample piece of code to highlight the relevant bits. When the code is compiled:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum LeaseState {
LEASE_NONE                   = 0x00,
LEASE_READ_CACHING           = 0x01,
LEASE_HANDLE_CACHING         = 0x02,
LEASE_WRITE_CACHING          = 0x04,
LEASE_RH_CACHING             = LEASE_READ_CACHING | LEASE_HANDLE_CACHING,
LEASE_RW_CACHING             = LEASE_READ_CACHING | LEASE_WRITE_CACHING,
LEASE_RWH_CACHING            = LEASE_READ_CACHING | LEASE_WRITE_CACHING |
                               LEASE_HANDLE_CACHING
};

LeaseState
updated_lease_state(LeaseState current, LeaseState new)
{
    return (new | (current ^ new));
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Updated lease state: " << updated_lease_state(LEASE_RW_CACHING, LEASE_READ_CACHING);
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

...this is the error seen:

```
$ g++ enum.cc
enum.cc:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘new’
enum.cc: In function ‘LeaseState updated_lease_state(LeaseState, LeaseState)’:
enum.cc:19: error: expected type-specifier before ‘|’ token
enum.cc:19: error: expected type-specifier before ‘)’ token
```

Can someone help me understand what's wrong with line 17?

Thanks!

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in C++, as you can also see from the highlighting on SO. change the variable name

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Thanks! Completely missed that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new is a reserved keyword!

```
LeaseState updated_lease_state(LeaseState current, LeaseState newState)
{
     return (newState | (current ^ newState));
}
```